# What happened to Snoke's face?

Tags: star-wars, snoke

We see from *The Force Awakens* that Supreme Leader Snoke has a significantly disfigured face.

[image: Snoke]

In *The Last Jedi*...

> ...Snoke dies.

My question:

> Now I thought that we'd possibly get some new backstory on Snoke in The Last Jedi, especially on the topic of Snoke's face. It seems clear that *something* must have happened to Snoke's face to account for the scaring and facial disfigurement. Yet I don't remember hearing anything in the film that explained Snoke's appearance. Did I miss something, or has what happened to Snoke been officially revealed somewhere else? Was he attacked at some point? Or is that just the way he's always been?

Comment: Down voted. In your question you basically say "We never get any information about Snoke, so what happened to his face?". Entirely non sense

Comment: @Edlothiad My question has a broader scope than just The Last Jedi (albeit it was triggered by it). The answer may well be found in interviews or other works. I have no particular beef with the other question but to my mind it's too broad and certainly doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It certainly would given that no new information is known.

Comment: @motoDrizzt There have been something in the film that I missed that points towards an answer. Or an answer from interviews or other media that I'm not aware of. Not knowing information which you think just may be put there somewhere is the reason you ask questions...

Comment: Seems very dupey to me, not least because the top answer on the other question literally contains all that we (currently) know about this mysterious figure.

Comment: @Valorum I can see why you say that but I disagree. As I said to Edlothiad, my question is broader than just The Last Jedi. It may be answerable from other media. Besides, the linked question is a poor fit as it's too broad. Not only does it not answer my question but it's asking for everything we know. As a precedent, allowing questions asking "Tell me everything we know about x" and pointing users there through duplicates when there are *any* specific questions related to x seems...dubious. It seems inevitable that the catchall answers won't deal with the specific points.